# Ruby gem development, how to use other gem functionality?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

this is my first time making rubygem, in my gem i need to use [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) gem, my question are:

1. How to i use fb_graph inside my gem, could you explain it ?
2. Is **s.add_dependency "fb_graph"** will automatically load fb_graph gem ? and its ok to puts **require 'rubygems'** and **require 'fb_graph'** inside **my_gem/lib/my_gem.rb** ? where **my_gem.rb** is ruby module.

Ok, thank you in advance and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest

```
s.add_dependency "fb_graph"
```

Should be enough, yes.  It's certainly ok to `require "rubygems"` and `require "fb_graph"`.  This is the intended approach.

Comment: yes it's work, i just lil'bit worries about my code, because difficult to find docs about ruby gem development that using another gems, thanks